# Matlab does not recognize 1394 camera

Tags: matlab, libdc1394

I have a 1394 camera connected with the computer as indicated below (the installations followed the instruction given https://www.mathworks.com/help/imaq/dcam-ieee-1394-firewire-hardware-on-windows.html#f16-76150 by Matlab). But the camera device does not show up in the Image Acquisition Explorer (see the screenshot below). It only recognizes a webcam.

There may be some potential issues with the 1394 host controller driver. I guessed the CMU driver used for the camera is not compatible with the 1394 host controller driver (dependent on PCIe hardware). Need to test a different PCI card to verify that.

[image]

[image]
However

Comment: Have you installed the [support package Add-Ons](https://www.mathworks.com/help/imaq/image-acquisition-support-packages-for-hardware-adaptors.html)?

Comment: It is installed. That's why the computer can recognize the camera device.

Comment: Did you connect your MathWorks representative? They should be able to help you.